# Creating a cookie for my Flash video to autoplay only once for a new user?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, cookies, dreamweaver

I have an .swf transparent video that auto-plays on a site, and I'd like to figure out how to configure a cookie that would disable autoplay for a returning user (unless of course they cleared their cookie).

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

I'm using action script 3.0.

Comment: You can use [shared objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d80.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)s for this kind of behavior. You initialize local storage, and check if a certain parameter is present. If yes, you don't play the video.

```
var so:SharedObject=SharedObject.getLocal();
if (so.data.havePlayed==1) { // played already
} else {
     // play video
}
```

Once your video finishes playing, you use the same code to get SO instance, and set the property.

```
var so:SharedObject=SharedObject.getLocal();
so.data.havePlayed=1;
```

Comment: `SharedObject.getLocal()` requires a name, like `SharedObject.getLocal("settings")`.

Comment: Thought something was awry. Still trying to implement this, and this may have been the issue.

Comment: I'm getting an 1151 namespace error on the second portion of code at "so" at the end of the animation, thoughts?

Comment: If I do this as stated, the video never auto-plays because the so.data doesn't get any data to begin with.

Comment: First of all, make the default behavior to auto-play, and only skip if the data is there (like @Vesper's example did). Second, you might not be writing the shared object data or it might not be allowed. What happens if you call [`flush()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush())?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for mentioning `flush()`, it is necessary to check if the data is saved. Although shared objects normally flush anyway when closed, ensuring that data is saved helps to debug issues.